# Is there a need to formally register activities performed under an LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, north-carolina

I am considering establishing an LLC. The forms that I have seen for North Carolina just have contact information but no actual description of the LLCs activities. Is there a need to describe the activities performed under the auspices of the LLC? How is an activity legally performed under the LLC?

In terms of liability, how can it be clear that I was performing some activity via the LLC, and not myself personally?

Also if there is a better stack exchange site for this type of question please let me know. I looked around but was surprised to find that there was no business related Stack exchange site, at least as far as I could find.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about legal liability and should be addressed to a local lawyer. There's a "Law@SE" stack as well, if you want to try. It's not a personal finance (or any finance) question.

Comment: I can try the other Stack as well. However it is common for individuals who are operating as sole proprietors to consider opening an LLC for personal finance reasons. Also the fact that there is a tag in this stack with limited liability company that has been used several hundred times give me the idea that it might be appropriate here.

Comment: I understand your confusion. Most questions about LLCs here are about taxes and book management. You're asking a legal question, not finances question.